# jquery toggleClass can't get to work

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get jquery .toggleClass to work with "this" and it's not working.  Can someone quickly point me in the right direction?  Thanks

Basically I'd just like to toggle the class from nonactive to active int his following example.

http://jsfiddle.net/6oqe0szq/2/

```
#contenttab {float: left;position: relative; padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px; ; width: 350px; color:     #f1f1f1; font-size: 18px; border-radius: 5px;transition: .2s ease-in-out; margin:10px; text-align: center; letter-spacing: 3px}

.notactive {background: #545b60; transition: .2s ease-in-out;}
.notactive:hover {background:#9adb24; transition: .2s ease-in-out;}       
.active {background: #9adb24 !important}


 <div id="content_controller">
        <div id="contenttab" class="notactive" onclick="left();">Test Info</div>
        <div id="contenttab" class="notactive" onclick="middle();">Test Templates</div>
        <div id="contenttab" class="notactive" onclick="right();">Test Questions</div>
 </div>

function left() {
$( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
}
function middle() {
$( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
}
function right() {
$( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty much everything is wrong in your code example. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/Lkcqufcc/

Comment: `id` should be unique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS fiddle didnt have Jquery included.

Updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kf45mcwf/)

Fixed your HTML to remove duplicate Id's they are unique. And removed your function calls.

```
<div id="content_controller">
    <div id="contenttab1" class="notactive">Test Info</div>
    <div id="contenttab2" class="notactive">Test Templates</div>
    <div id="contenttab3" class="notactive">Test Questions</div>
```

Updated your CSS so that it used classes.

```
 .notactive {
     float: left;
     position: relative;
     padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
     width: 350px;
     color: #f1f1f1;
     font-size: 18px;
     border-radius: 5px;
     transition: .2s ease-in-out;
     margin:10px;
     text-align: center;
     letter-spacing: 3px
 }
 .notactive {
     background: #545b60;
     transition: .2s ease-in-out;
 }
 .notactive:hover {
     background:#9adb24;
     transition: .2s ease-in-out;
 }
 .active {
     background: #9adb24 !important
 }
```

Added jquery, document.ready, and function call.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.notactive').click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, works, and I suppose I can toggleClass the other classes in order to remove .active from the previous clicks right?

Answer (score 0):

try

http://jsfiddle.net/6oqe0szq/7/

Note the script tags appearing above your html. Also, you need to pass in the object that is being acted upon. i called it `me`

```
<script>
    function left(me) {
        $( me ).toggleClass( "active" );
    }
    function middle(me) {
        $( me ).toggleClass( "active" );
    }
    function right(me) {
        $( me ).toggleClass( "active" );
    }

</script>
<div id="content_controller">
    <div id="contenttab" class="notactive" onclick="left(this);">Test Info</div>
    <div id="contenttab" class="notactive" onclick="middle(this);">Test Templates</div>
    <div id="contenttab" class="notactive" onclick="right(this);">Test Questions</div>
</div>
```